# visual c# application havey flickering on another machine

Tags: multithreading, frameworks

i have developed an application (game) on visual studio 2012 (WFA) in C#, the application includes multithreading and graphics objects (pictureboxs, bit maps, labels...).

now the app runs great on the source pc (the computer it was developed on). but when i try to run it on my laptop it's run with very heavy flickering which is very weird.

source pc - windows 7 net framework 4.6 .
laptop    - windows 10 net framework 4.6

*note - both are very strong machines who can run battlefield 4 with no problem.

what is going on??

Comment: Most likely it's either a) a hardware issue ("very strong machines" does not give specs that could be compared), or b) micro$^^t screwed something up when they went from w7 to w10.  I'm guessing the latter....

Comment: "screwed something up when they went from w7 to w10"                             
so is there anything i can do to make it compatible to win 10 ?

Comment: Check the drivers that are needed by your app, try installing VS on the laptop and debugging it there, that's where I would start

Comment: i did tried it....no success so far  :(  ....anyone??

Comment: What is the "it" you tried? installing drivers? installing VS on the laptop? debugging on the laptop?

Comment: 'installing drivers? installing VS on the laptop? debugging on the laptop?' yas i have tried all of those, just can't determine what causing the bug, is it possible thet win 10 is the problem?

Comment: Are both machines either 32 bit or 64 bit, or are the architectures different?  Run `All Programs > Accessories > System Tools > System Information` on both machines and **edit your question** to include the *System Summary* for each, and considering it sounds like a display problem, the *Components/Display* page for each.  ... and yes, "it [is] possible thet[sic] win 10 is the problem"

Comment: yes the architectures are different!!, source pc - 32bit. laptop - 64bit ....interesting

Answer (score 0):

You've got a software component issue - something that works correctly in 32 bit winDoze is broken in the 64 bit version.  Try building your application as specifically 32 bit and run it on the 64 bit machine.  Either it will complain about a missing (32 bit) driver (or other softwar component) or it will work correctly.

Comment: FKEinternet according to your advice i have tried to use the Configuration Manager and build my app adjusted to 64 bit hoping it will solve the issue. unfortunately it didn't work, the problem is still there on the 64 bit machine, i can't figure this out! so annoying...

Comment: That's not what I said - I said build it as a **32 bit** application on your 64 bit laptop:  You know that the *32 bit* version works correctly on your desktop machine, so you want to test if a *32 bit version* works on your laptop - the objective is to eliminate differences until you find the one that's causing the problem.

Comment: ok i guess i don't understand what do you mean exactly. tell me please, when you say  "I said build it as a 32 bit application on your 64 bit laptop", how to do it? you mean to use the Configuration Manager tool? or to build the whole app from the start in the 64 bit laptop??

Comment: Yes, use the Configuration Manager tool ***on your 64 bit laptop*** to build a 32 bit version of the application.  You will only be able to figure out what is going wrong by debugging ***on the laptop***, and your first step is to see if a 32 bit version - which is what is running correctly on your desktop - works correctly ***on the laptop***